# c++:error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'A<TYPE>' to 'B<TYPE>'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, polymorphism

I have a base class A and it has a subclass B.
A overrides the + operator and B overrides it as well,calls the parent's +operator, and casts the result to B. Then I am getting the error message:

> error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'A'
>   to 'B'

I thought polymorphism worked in a way that should allow this to work?

Comment: some sample code would be helpful.

Comment: Can you add an A and a B, and what would you expect the result type to be?

Answer (score 8):

In polymorphism you cannot convert `A` to `B`, you can convert `B` to `A`. B is a kind of A, but A is NOT a kind of B.

For example, in the classic Shape classes. If you have a class `Shape` and a class `Rectangle` that extends [inherit from] `Shape`, you cannot convert a `Shape` instance to `Rectangle`, but you CAN cast a `Rectangle` to `Shape`, because it is a 'kind of' Shape.

Comment: Is there a way to make it castable the other way around?

Comment: @James: It doesn't make sense, since `B` might have additional data `A` doesn't have. If you think you want it this way, you probably need to reconsider your design. However, a possible work-around is creating a constructor: `B(A)`, and creating a new instance of `B`, and returning it. I however repeat, this work-around has a [code-smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), and a [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) should probably be a better idea.

Comment: `B* bptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(object);`

Comment: Note that @MooingDuck's comment is correct **only if the object is indeed of type B**, otherwise you will get a runtime error.

Comment: And in this case, `A operator+(A,A)` will _not_ return something that's really a B, so `dynamic_cast` won't help.