# c++ how to inherit operator that returns specific type

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a class 'A' that overrides the + operator, and a subclass 'B'.

I want to inherit 'A's + operator but instead of returning type A I want to return type B.

How can I go about doing this? I tried calling the parent's operator from B and casting the result to an A object but it won't let me cast a parent to a child

Can my + operator somehow return a generic 'A' pointer or something?

Comment: Could you provide the signature of the + operator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++:error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'A<TYPE>' to 'B<TYPE>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614313/cerror-c2440-function-style-cast-cannot-convert-from-atype-to-bty)

Answer (score 2):

It could - no technical reason it couldn't - it just violates some expectations when using operators.  So if this is code for yourself, go for it, but if it's going to be read or used by other people, I'd reconsider for the following reasons:

1. Expected behaviour is that operators like `+=` and `*=` return a reference to the object they were called on after modifying that object.  Operators like `+` and `*` return a new object (they pretty much have to, as the implication is that the object they're called on isn't changed).  They don't return a pointer to a new object because:
2. No one expects them to, so they won't think to `delete` an object they get back from an operator, which will cause memory leaks, and:
3. You can't chain operators that return pointers; an expression like `MyClass a = b + c + d;` won't work, because the return type (`MyClass*`) won't match the argument type you need to pass into the operator (probably `const MyClass&`).
4. Returning a *reference* to a new object lets you work around #3, and still supports polymorphism, but you're still stuck with #2, and that's the worse of the pair.  The same applies to overloading the operator to take either a pointer or a reference.

Ultimately, just do whatever makes life easiest for whoever's going to be using the code - and if it's just you, you can do anything you want.  Just be careful if it's going to fall into other people's hands, because they *will* make assumptions.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** An example that returns a reference to a new object:

```
A& A::operator + (const A& other) const
{
    A* temp = new A(); // <- This is why it's a potential memory leak
    /* Do some stuff */
    return *temp;
}
```

But, having had a little more time to think about this, I'd propose an alternative: Define an `=` operator for B that takes an A as its argument.  Then you could do things like this:

```
B b1;
B b2;
B b3 = b1 + b2;
```

And it wouldn't matter that `b1 + b2` returned an A, because it was converted back to a B during the `=`.  If this works for you, I'd recommend it above any other method, as it lets all the operators have expected behaviours.

Comment: Can you give some sample code to how returning a generic reference would work?

Comment: @James - Just put up some example code for you.  And another suggestion, which I'd recommend over any of my previous thoughts.  Cheers!

Comment: Another option is to return a type that hides the polymorphism in a member variable of pointer type.  This type then acts polymorhpically, but can be returned by value.  `auto_ptr`/`unique_ptr`/`scoped_ptr`/`shared_ptr` are close, but they try to act like pointers.  A custom smart pointer could act like the object.

Answer (score 2):

I frequently see it done in the following way:

```
class A {
    int a;
    A(int rhs) :a(rhs) {} 
public:
    A& operator+=(const A& rhs) {a+=rhs.a; return *this} 
    A operator+(const A& rhs) {return a+rhs.a;} 
};

class B : public A {
    int b;
public:
    B(const B& rhs) :A(rhs), b(rhs.b) {}
//                               VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
    B& operator+=(const B& rhs) {A::operator+=(rhs); b+=rhs.b; return *this;}
    B operator+(const B& rhs) {return B(*this)+=rhs;}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve this problem is to implement `operator+` in terms of `operator+=`. So roughly:

```
A::operator+=(const A& right) { /* stuff */ }
B::operator+=(const B& right) { static_cast<A&>(*this) += right; /* stuff */ }
operator+(B left, const B& right) { return B += right; }
```

Comment: This is interesting, but could it be done the other way around, instead?  By implementing `+=` in terms of `+`.  The current version has the unexpected property that `left + right` changes the value `left`.  I'd like it better than my suggestions if it weren't for that...

Comment: @XavierHolt: `left` is a copy. So it does not matter that it gets changed because the caller will never see the change.

Comment: @Zan - Aha!  Missed that.  This is pretty clever, then.

Comment: @Xavier Holt In fact this is the C++ canonical way to implement `+` and `+=` (for reasons already mention in an above comment).